# simple text editor for iPhone

Tags: iphone, text-editor

Is there any simple text editor available for iphone having features like BOLD, ITALIC and changing colors and fonts? I want to add this functionality to my iphone app.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to develop it through Quartz2d.In otherwords ,you can through handling CGContext of UIView. see the [Quartz2d programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html).for example you can give bold font through

```
 CGContextSelectFont (context,"Helvetica-Bold",12, kCGEncodingMacRoman);
```

Answer (score 0):

Text Editor Pro seems to have those features. Pretty expensive though:  http://itunes.apple.com/dk/app/text-editor-pro/id316815447?mt=8

Answer (score 0):

Oliver Drobnik (aka Cocoanetics) is working on a rich text editor for iOS.

It won't be free, unfortunately. However, he has released a sizeable chunk of code that serves as the foundation of his rich editor here: https://github.com/Cocoanetics/NSAttributedString-Additions-for-HTML

It takes HTML and turns it into core text. A lot of hard work right there.

That, on its own, is not a rich editor, but like I said, it serves as the foundation of one. You could use it to write your own, if you don't want to pay up for Oliver's when he's finished. You can see what Oliver has been working on here: http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/01/rich-text-editing-on-ios/